# How to upgrade lucene files from 2.2 to 4.3.1

Tags: java, lucene

I have a huge indexed data in lucene V 2.2, and i have upgrade my lucene jars to 4.3.1.
is the new version support upgrading 2.2 files. if yes ? how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene guarantees index backwards compatibility to the previous major version.  This means, Lucene 4.X should be able to read an index generated by Lucene 3.0 and later.  With earlier versions (such as in your case, with 2.2), index backwards compatibility is not supported.

A possible solution might be to upgrade first to v3.6, and when you have your index in that format, then move up to v4.3.